# Linux Bash Script Read While Loop Issue using Curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I'm new to writing scripts in bash and I am having an issue with performing a while read loop when trying to access data from the star wars api. My problem is that I am trying to get the name of all the characters and the name of all their associated starships (can be more than one). My below code will get the name of the character, then get the url to be passed to the spacecraft and retrieve the name of the spacecraft.The issue is when I'm trying to put this all together the output seems to overwrite what person belongs to what spacecraft rather than assigning each person to that spacecraft. I would expect to see taking Luke Skywalker as the example:

```
Luke Skywalker X-Wing
Luke Skywalker Imperial Shuttle
```

But the output I am getting is blank for Luke Skywalker as the X-Wing seems to attach to another character as the code progresses through all people associated with it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Bash Shell Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url='https://swapi.co/api'

n=1
while true
do
    response=$( curl -sL -H 'Accept: application/json' ${url}/people 
    page=${n} )
    if [[ ${response} =~ .*detail.*Not.* ]]; then
            break
    fi
    n=$((n + 1))
    name=$( echo ${response} | jq -r '.results[] | "\(.name)"' | tr -d '"')
    echo ${response} | jq -r '.results[] | { starships: .starships }' | 
    egrep /starships/ |\
    sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ',' |\
            while read shipurl
            do
                    curl -s ${shipurl} | jq '.name' | tr -d '"'
            done |\
            while read shipname
            do
            echo  "${name}" " ${shipname}"
            done

done
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is a mad mad script! :)

Answer (score 0):

oh boy! This should be done using `python`... but here, I gave it a try. Not a hardcore `Star Wars` fan, so don't know if this turns out ok, but this will give you some more idea...

Note, I have disabled `while true` for my test case. I am sure some of those `jq` related stuff can be cleaned up more. I use `pilots` for each of these `starships` and match according to that because each `character name` has more than one matched `starship`.

```
$ cat crazystarwars.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

url='https://swapi.co/api'
n=1
#while true
#do
    response=$(curl -sL -H 'Accept: application/json' "${url}/people?page=${n}")
    if [[ ${response} =~ .*"detail".*"Not".* ]]; then
            break
    fi

    readarray -t name < <( echo "${response}" | jq -r '.results[] | "\(.name)"')
    readarray -t shipurls < <(echo ${response} | jq -r '.results[] | { starships: .starships }' | egrep /starships/ | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ',')

    for p in "${shipurls[@]}"
    do

        shipname=$(curl -s ${p} | jq '.name' | tr -d '"')
        readarray -t _pilots < <(curl -s ${p} | jq -r '.pilots[]' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'curl -s {}' | jq '.name')

        for _name in "${name[@]}"
        do
            if [[ "${_pilots[@]}" =~ "${_name}" ]]; 
            echo "${_name} ${shipname}"
            break
            fi
        done

    done
#   ((n++))
#done
```

Output is something like (not entirely sure if its the right one):

```
$ ./crazystarwars.sh
Luke Skywalker X-wing
Luke Skywalker Imperial shuttle
Darth Vader TIE Advanced x1
Luke Skywalker X-wing
Obi-Wan Kenobi Jedi starfighter
Obi-Wan Kenobi Trade Federation cruiser
Obi-Wan Kenobi Naboo star skiff
Obi-Wan Kenobi Jedi Interceptor
Obi-Wan Kenobi Belbullab-22 starfighter
```